# Is it a good practice to merge include directives in one file

Tags: c++, header-files

I think that all is in the title.

Say we have a project with this structure:

```
+ src
    main.cpp
    task1.cpp
    task2.cpp
+ includes
    main.h
    task1.h
    task2.h
```

both `task1.h` and `task2.h` uses `<QPushButton>` and `<QLabel>`.

is it a good idea to create an other header file ( `core.h` ) and put this includes into

```
// core.h
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
```

and then call it from each `task1.h` and `task2.h` files.

is there any changes that can be noticed when doing it this way ( compilation time, programming restrictions, ... )

Comment: It will be better if you can avoid including header file in a header file. Use forward declaration instead and declare corresponding header file in the cpp file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would only do this if you were using "precompiled headers". Otherwise it doesn't make much sense.

- Use forward declarations where possible.
- Add includes in the files where you need a full declaration of a type.

Using a header file where you put all include files makes impossible for the build system to track the dependencies of changed files. Suddenly all your code depends on your `core.h` header. If this header is changed, all your code has to be recompiled, even there is no actual change.

Comment: Using "forward declarations where possible" is good advice only if the forward declarations are in a header that's part of the library declaring and defining those symbols.  A forward declaration header (e.g. `<iosfwd>`) should be provided with any library that's large enough to warrant clients wanting such declarations, providing a useful set of declarations can be made while avoiding a useful quantity of other includes.

Comment: @TonyD Yes, this is good advice if you create a library. As I understand the question, it is asked if you create a header for the use of your own project.

Answer (score 1):

IMO core headers are good practice:

- for small projects;
- if you restrict them to containing things that seldom change.

A `core.h` doesn't scale well to medium- or large-sized projects. There are several problems with this approach:

- it is difficult to analyze or manage dependencies when everything is dependent upon everything in this one file;
- whenever anything in that one header changes, everything will be recompiled;
- instead of thinking about where things really belong, programmers just keep dumping things into this one file;
- the namespace for every compilation unit is polluted with everything that is in that one file.